# Set the height of imageview according to screen from the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making the layout and using the layout_weight and weight_sum. I am making the orientation of linear layout to horizontal so i am able to set the width of imageview 1/3 of the screen. But I dont know how to set the height of imageview to 1/3 of the screen.

Please help me to set the imageview height to 1/3 of the screen from the layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/savedImageView"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:background="@drawable/background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you put an outer horizontal linearlayout like this, you will both have 1/3 screen width and 1/3 screen height for your imageview. The inner linearlayout is vertical so you can just use that if you just need 1/3 screen height

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/out"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/savedImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/yourdrawablename" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used it set the imageview 1/3 but inside linearlayout cover the entire height of the screen. I want its should be also 1/3.

Comment: Well weight is used either as horizontal or vertical so you can't change setting your linearlayout size like that. You asked for the imageview and this is the way of achieving it. If you want precise result for the outerlayouts too, you must do it programmatically.

Answer (score 14):

Use this:

```
int displayWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

imageView.getLayoutParams().height = displayWidth / 3;
```

Comment: I want to do same from the xml layout. Then how can i ?

Comment: seems to work, except for one case, if image height is smaller that 1/3 of the screen height, it will not be scaled up to 1/3 of screen height, EDIT: to make it work we need to set `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in the ImageView xml definition.

Answer (score -2):

Do u need some thing like this or please elaborate u r problem more so that i can help u

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/savedImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="414dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.52"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: From this code it set the width but not the height. I want to set the height and width from weightsum and layout_weight property.

Comment: uplaod the image how u want to display u r layout i am not getting u r question

Comment: I mean i pasted the code above in the question in which it set the width of imageview according to screeen width but i want to set the both height and width 1/3 according to screen. I success to set either width and height but not both of them from layout properties

Comment: Check my answer which handles both width and height.