# android change button size according to device screen size

Tags: android, height, size, width

I want to adjust my app design to any android devices, I already tried to set elements size properties by percentage but i get in truble with this way so I tried this code:(set width and height by device screen size / 5)

```
public void fixButtonSizes (){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width1 = size.x;
    int height1 = size.y;
    Button button1vid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1vid.setHeight(height1 / 5);
    button1vid.setWidth(width1 / 5);
}
```

and it`s does not work for me too

Comment: May be this one help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944910/set-the-height-of-imageview-according-to-screen-from-the-layout

Answer (score 0):

To use percentage width or height in android you should wrap your elements inside a `LinearLayout` and use the `layout_weight` property of the element. Also you have to put `0dp` in the `layout_width` or `layout_width` according to the dimension you want.

To calculate which height or width an element will have, you have to sum all the layout_weight of the elements in the layout and divide by the weight of the element.

For instance, if you want to create a 5 buttons horizontally with the same width you can use this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 3"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 4"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will clarify you.

Comment: i have some issue withthis line of code: android:layout_width="0dp" it`s says that it will be invisible

Comment: have you wrapped all the views inside a `LinearLayout` and added `android:layout_weight="1"`??

Comment: yes , i want to say that i have more linearlayout but this specific one is define like you told me to define

Comment: can you post the layout?

Comment: i found out that the problem was that in the linearlayout properties i put this line         android:orientation="vertical"    and when i removed this it`s solve the problem but i want this orientation for my design so how can i have both